# Predictions based on k-fold Cross Validation, which model is used (Caret)

Tags: r, cross-validation, random-forest, caret

I am sorry if there is an obvious or intuitive answer to this, which I missed.

We have tuned the hyperparameters of a RF using Grouped 10 - Fold CV (repeated 5 times), to obtain the values for *mtry* and *ntree* which result in the highest accuracy.

I understand the concept of (grouped) K-Fold Cross Validation. However my first basic question is how is the hyperparameter tuning from caret incorporated into this resampling technique? In a toy example where we want to test `mtry = c(1,2)` and `ntree = c(500,1000)` (meaning 4 possible combinations of hyperparameters) would caret run the complete 10 Fold CV repeated 5 times, for each of the 4 possible combination of mtry and ntree?

Or does caret iterate through the different hyperparameter combinations in the repeats of the CV?

Furthermore if we want to make predictions about a novel dataset (df2) based on the rf model (output from caret hyperparam tuning), which model will be used? Since in a 10-Fold CV there are 10 models trained on (10-1 Fold of data) and evaluated in 1 fold. I know that the performance metrics are averaged, however I can't really imagine that the same is true for the model.

```
transfer <- predict(rf.df1,newdata = df2)
confusionMatrix(df2$Class,transfer)
#which model is used here for the predictions?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model used is the one trained on the *whole* of the training sample using the hyperpameters yielding the optimal average performance based on the CV procedure defined.